# How to return a character set after matching a specific string in a regular expression

Tags: regex, sox

I'm actually using using a command line tool called `sox` to retrieve information about an audio file. This returns the following output:

```
Samples read:            449718
Length (seconds):     28.107375
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.999969
Minimum amplitude:    -0.999969
Midline amplitude:     0.000000
Mean    norm:          0.145530
Mean    amplitude:     0.000291
RMS     amplitude:     0.249847
Maximum delta:         1.316925
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.033336
RMS     delta:         0.064767
Rough   frequency:          660
Volume adjustment:        1.000
```

I'd like to extract the values out of this using a regular expression. So far I have `/^Length \(seconds\):\s*[0-9.]*/m` which matches `Length (seconds):     28.107375` but I just want the value.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Here's a link to an online tool that I'm playing with:
[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/WHa9Er4glE)

Answer (score 1):

Two options (I'm not familiar with sox, so I'm not sure how exactly this would work in sox):

1. You can use lookbehind to match the first part. This works in case the regex engine allows variable length lookbehind: `/(?<=^Length \(seconds\)\:\s*)[\d.]*/`
2. You can capture the value in a group to reference it later: `/^Length \(seconds\):\s*([\d.]*)/`. this will work if sox has a capture group functionality. In this case, the value will be held in the first capture group ($1 in ruby)

Comment: Thanks for your response @davidrac, some good terminology to look into here, namely: variable length lookbehind and capture groups. The mentioning of `sox` was just for background info. I'll be executing `sox` through ruby anyway so I'm thinking ruby would be best for the regex.

Comment: This show the matched groups that you get back, very useful: [Rubular matched group for length value](http://rubular.com/r/sJ3TQHOL44)

Answer (score 1):

"soxi -D filename" returns the length of filename in seconds. Just the number, nothing else. Information about SoXI can be found [here](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxi.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^Length \(seconds\):/ { print $NF }'
```